# GitHub action for issue_comment doesn't shown in checks for PR

Tags: github, github-actions

I created a GitHub action on:issue_comment, I can see the flow running only in the action tab, but not in the PR, where I made the comment.
I want to comment in a PR and trigger a check on that PR (not on master)

here is my workflow:

```
name: issue-comment-CI-test 

on: 
  issue_comment:    
    types: [created]    
jobs:   
  build:    

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  

    steps:  
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1 
    - name: Run a one-line script   
      run: echo Hello, world!   
    - name: Run a multi-line script 
      run: echo ${{ github.event.comment.body }}
```

currently, I'm just printing the comment body, But I plan to check the body, and if it is equal to "run integration tests" then I'll run my integration tests (maven)

Comment: You will have to get the PR ID and check the PR out manually.

Comment: You will have to show your workflow file. GitHub actions do not run in the context of a branch or issue or pr, so it really all depends on how you have configured your workflow

Comment: @smac89 I have added the workflow

Comment: @dan1st  can you give an example? I don't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to checkout to the PR origin. For that, first make a API request to the pr url and fetch all ref.
Then do the checkout on the fetched repo and branch.

Step1

```
- name: Github API Request
    id: request
    uses: octokit/request-action@v2.0.0
    with:
      route: ${{ github.event.issue.pull_request.url }}
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Step 2

```
- name: Checkout PR Branch
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      repository: ${{ fromJson(steps.request.outputs.data).head.repo.full_name }}
      ref: ${{ steps.pr_data.outputs.branch }}
```

You can follow the following example, specially the `GitHub API Request` part.
I've also implemented it in one of our workflows, you can take reference from that as well.

https://github.com/adrianjost/workflow-trigger-comment-example/blob/master/.github/workflows/demo.yml
https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager/blob/master/.github/workflows/android-debug-artifact-ondemand.yml

Comment: I follow your example, works fine! but any idea how can I link the action build to the PR? currently it shows just the first build which is related to the PR opened hook

Comment: This answer omits a step, the one that sets the `pr_data` data. It's present in both examples

Comment: Just wondering, why is `pull_request:  types: [opened]` required here?

Answer (score 1):

Used built-in [gh command](https://github.com/cli/cli) to fetch the branch instead of using actions/checkout.

```
name: issue-comment-CI-test

on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - run: |
        gh pr checkout ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
        # do your job...
      env:
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # required for gh
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkout the Pull Request. You can get the PR ID by using `{{ GITHUB_REF }}`.

You can checkout the PR with:

```
git fetch origin pull/{{ GITHUB_REF }}/head:PR
git checkout PR
```

See https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally, https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onevent_nametypes, https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/using-environment-variables
 and https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/ for reference.

Comment: GITHUB_REF is always master also if i comment on PR/branch

Comment: What about `{{github.event.id}}`?

Comment: Or `{{github.event.pull_request.id}}`

Comment: wrote it hardcoded, and still, the check doesn't show up in the PR checks, only in the git hub repo actions

Comment: Maybe use `on:pull_request_review_comment` or something like that?

Comment: I finally made the link to PR by sending a comment with the build url:

Comment: @Brachi Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Brachi That's exactly what I'm trying to do, what do you mean "by sending a comment with the build url" you send a comment from the action? to where?

Comment: Yes, I'm sending a comment to the PR, including reference to the build ID, I also added a test report, in order to see the check itself in the PR checks, Here is full workflow https://github.com/brachi-wernick/githubActionPlayground/blob/main/.github/workflows/integration-test.yml

Answer (score 0):

I am using `xt0rted/pull-request-comment-branch@v2` action to know which branch i must checkout to and `mshick/add-pr-comment@v2` to post comment in the PR which triggered this action.

Also since the action does not show up in the "checks for PR" i am posting a comment which contains the link for the github action run which the user can click to check the status as the action runs

```yaml
name: Chatops plan - Integration tests

on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  your_job:
    if: >
      github.event.issue.pull_request &&
      startsWith(github.event.comment.body, 'run integration tests')
    name: your_job
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Fetch Branch Name
        id: fetch-branch-name
        uses: xt0rted/pull-request-comment-branch@v2

      - name: Check out code from ${{ steps.fetch-branch-name.outputs.head_ref }}
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ steps.fetch-branch-name.outputs.head_ref }}
      
      - name: Post response to GitHub PR
        uses: mshick/add-pr-comment@v2
        with:
          message: |
            Action started. Click [here](https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}) to see the status.
```